# Compare a variable with the values in an array in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have set my arrays like this:

```
SET ORG[0]=Microsoft
SET ORG[1]=Google
SET ORG[2]=Yahoo
SET ORG[3]=Snapchat
SET ORG[4]=Whatsapp
SET ORG[5]=Facebook
```

Then I do a find in one of the files to get the value stored in the file:

```
For /F Tokens^=10^ Delims^=^" %%A in ('Find /I "%Client%"^<"C:\Env\Test\test.xml"') Do Echo "%%A" & SET "ORG=%%A"
```

Where `ORG` can be any of the above mentioned array values depending on what's stored in the file. For example say for this instance:

```
ECHO %ORG% gives Google.
```

I would like to compare my `%ORG%` value fetched from the file against the set array values and If its equal then I want my batch script to:

```
GOTO :Action Else 
ECHO "Client Name Not Found"
```

I am not sure how to compare a variable with the values in the array?

Comment: And your XML file How it looks ?

Comment: @Hackoo the information that my find would fetch would be from this line of the xml - `<Org Updated="date" Owner="Test" Version="2/1/3/4"Database="Test" Client="Name">`. I am able to get 'Name' from the xml so thats not an issue. All i need to know here is how to compare %ORG% variable with the fixed values stored in the array. the solution should cover any additional array value which might be added in the future.

Comment: @Hackoo I want to check the value fetched from the xml and stored in my %ORG% to be compared against the values stored in the array. Something `if %ORG% == ORG[] GOTO Action ELSE ECHO Client Not found & GOTO Action2` please ignore the syntax here i am just trying to explain my requirement

Comment: Could you `set ORG[ | find /i "%%~A" >NUL && (echo Found) || (echo Not Found)` or similar?

Comment: @rojo I would actually prefer to compare the values because thats the requirement rather than just checking for null or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set ORG[ 2^>nul ') do if "%%b"=="%ORG" goto action

echo Client not found.
```

The `set` command lists the existing variables that start `ORG[` in the format `org[3]=Snapchat` Setting `delims` to `=` only assigns `ORG[3]` to `%%a` and `Snapchat` to `%%b`.

If such a match is found, the client is valid on the list. If the `for` exhausts all entries, processing simply proceeds to the next instruction in the file.

To make the comparison case-insensitive, use `if /i` in place of `if`

Comment: I have tried the above solution `for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b in ('set ORG[` 2^>nul ') do if /i "%%c"=="%ORG%"  GOTO action` but it doesnt seem to be going to "Action" even when the %ORG% value is found as Microsoft from the xml.  Please note that i have changed the value of %%a to %%b because i have used %%A in the previous loop and it has the value fetched from the xml

Comment: change the `if` to an `echo` which will then display each comparison. You should then be able to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: i did and it just proceeds to the next instruction `Echo not found`here is the command `for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b in ('set ORG[ 2^>nul ') do echo found      
 Echo not found` . I am definite the value of ORG is not null as i can see & display it using ECHO %ORG%

Comment: I asked you to replace the `if` with `echo` for a specific reason. The resultant statement, ` ECHO /i "%%c"=="%ORG%" GOTO action` would display each value of `%%c` against `%ORG%`. Since no `echo found` appears to be generated, it would appear that `org[` has not been established. Use a `set org` command before the `for /f`... line to see the values of all variables with names starting `org` (batch is *generally* case-insensitive, and I hate CaMeLcAsE)

Comment: I tried this way and it seems to be ok. What do you think `set len=6
set i=0
:loop
if %i% equ %len% goto ClientNotFound
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%j in (`set ORG[%i%]`) do (
 if "%%j"=="%Client%" GOTO RUNPATCH_Custom
)
set /a i=%i%+1
goto loop`

Comment: Magoo I think there is an erroneous backtick following `set ORG[` and @irish first comment still contains it, ending the code tag. I'll edit your answer to remove it.

Comment: @LotPings : Well spotted! I can see it now I've cleaned my screen!